# printing a vector as a c() call in brew

Tags: r

I am writing code that automatically generates R scripts based on a set of parameters and brew template.  One of the parameters is a vector `x.names` and I would like to print that vector to the script in a form that would get a processed correctly by the R interpreter.  For example

```
x.names = <%= data$x.names %>
```

results in this after being processed by brew:

```
x.names = c('my', 'x.names', 'vector')
```

Is this possible in brew?  Or is a there a function in R that prints R structures in a form that the R interpreter would process correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `deparse()`?

```
x.names = c('my', 'x.names', 'vector')
deparse(x.names)
# [1] "c(\"my\", \"x.names\", \"vector\")"
cat(deparse(x.names), "\n")
# c("my", "x.names", "vector") 

d <- c(7,-9,8)
deparse(d)
# [1] "c(7, -9, 8)"
eval(parse(text=deparse(d)))
# [1]  7 -9  8
```